# how can an UIAlertView button calls another function?

Tags: objective-c, uialertview, modalviewcontroller

```
 -(void)buPressed{

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Game Over"
                                                        message:@"YOU LOST! ALL YOUR BASE ARE BELONG TO US!"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Publish", nil];

    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];

    }

    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(buttonIndex==0){
        NSLog(@"%d",buttonIndex);

    }
    else{
        [self bPressed];
    }   

    }

    -(void)bPressed{

    ModalViewConroller *yeniSayfa=[[ModalViewConroller alloc] init];

    yeniSayfa.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

    [self presentModalViewController:yeniSayfa animated:YES];

    [yeniSayfa release];

    //Restore to Defaults
    [button_1 setSelected:NO];
    [button_2 setSelected:NO];
    [button_3 setSelected:NO];
    [button_4 setSelected:NO];
    [button_5 setSelected:NO];
    [button_6 setSelected:NO];
    slider.value=50.00;
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Smiley_00025.png"];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(81, 43, image.size.width, image.size.height);  
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];


    }
```

This is my code i want to make the publish button to call bPressed function but it is giving a warning and the program crashes when i touch the publish button i want to open a modalview when i push the publish button can anybody help me?

Comment: Please post the warning, it would be helpful.

Comment: did you specify this method in the header file?

Comment: Did you declare -(void)bPressed below the interface in your .h file?

Comment: warning: 'MainScreenContoller' may not respond to '-bPressed'
this is the warning mainscreencontroller is my view class

Comment: @Danny That's the compiler warning you that when you're calling `bPressed` from the `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method, it hasn't found the method yet (you haven't defined the prototype). That's not why it crashes, though...

Comment: Thanks for all i forgot it to write in to the header file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the function in your header file so that other objects (in this case an instance of UIAlertView, since its delegate is set to your class) know that this method exists.

So, in your whatever_class.h file, add the following line below the `@interface{   }`:

```
-(void)bPressed;
```